# NullReferenceException in Release mode of Xamarin application

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

In simple POST request to my REST API I am doing object serialization into JSON as follow:

```
var userDto = new { user = new { login = Username, password = Password } };
var jsonPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userDto, Formatting.Indented);
```

in Debug mode everything works fine, but in the Release mode `jsonPayload` variable is null and in my try/catch I am getting `NullReferenceException`. Why value of this variable is different in Debug/Release and how to solve this?

This is Android application and I have enabled Internet Permission.

Comment: try cleaning the solution, removing optimization and linking in the `Release` configurations

Answer (score 5):

Most likely your issue is due to the [Xamarin Linker](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/) stripping out the *"unused assemblies"* from you code. The default linking setting is different for release and debug builds which is probably why you are seeing this difference.

Try setting the "Linking" option (you can find it under the project setting for your android project under Android Options) to *SDK Assemblies Only* or *None* and see if that works.

Comment: Set to "SDK assemblies only" and add System.Core to "Skip linking assemblies". It's the only way to work. Tks Jack

Comment: @Alexandre Glad to help, I encountered a very similar issue until I realized what the issue was.

Comment: Xamarin and it's BUG's, sometimes it's very frustrating to work with, so many workarounds!

Comment: @headsvk Can't really argue, I did too. The information is sort of contained within the Xamarin Docs but really isn't that clear.

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json depends on System.Core on runtime?
Here's my stacktrace but I wouldn't get it, even if I saw it. https://gist.github.com/headsvk/99f7754dc2fdf28175ba

Comment: @headsvk I'm not sure what it depends on, but I think the problem has to do with the Linker stripping out the default constructors from the class that JSON.Net is trying to deserialize because it isn't detecting that it is being used. If setting the linking option to none works then you should be able to set it back to link and have it ignore those assemblies.

Comment: Yes, something is wrong with the linking process. Adding System.Core to skipped assemblies works as per Alexandre's comment but Xamarin team should look into that.

Comment: Thanks, saved lots of my time.!

Comment: Linking = none - work for me. Thanks, I spent all day for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had to resign using anonymous object because I don't know why `JSON.NET` in `Release` mode cause this error. After reimplementing it as follow everything works fine. Does anybody has any idea why? ;)

```
UserSignInModel uDTO = new UserSignInModel()
            {
                user = new UserSignInDTO()
                {
                    login = Username,
                    password = Password,
                }
            };

var jsonPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(uDTO, Formatting.Indented);
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, but i didn't find a real solution for it. After narrowing down when this problem started to show up, i found out that it happened after updating the json.net package.

This is the difference, Before:

```
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.3" targetFramework="MonoAndroid403" />
```

After:

```
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.6" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
```

I just reversed the package as a temporary solution right now. Would love to hear some insight and solution for this problem!